# Why if I don't explic explicitly set an height of this div it expands upwards and it falls below of the previous elements?

Tags: html, css, layout, xhtml

I am not so into CSS and I have the following doubt about why I have this behavior and how to correctly handle this situation.

Into a very very old page I have something like this:

```
<div class="panel-wrapper">
    <div class="panel-content">
        <table class="standard-table-cls" style="width: 98%;">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="6" style="text-align: center; border-left: 0">SEDE LEGALE</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Ragione Sociale</td>
                <td colspan=5>
                    <input type="TEXT" name="ragsoc" size=60 maxlength=100 <%=master?"":"readonly"%>
                           class="testosmallUpper" value="<%= ragioneSociale %>" onblur="MakeItUpper(event,this)">
                </td>
            </tr>
            ..............................................................
            ..............................................................
            ..............................................................
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

..................................................
..................................................
..................................................

<div id="anagrafica">
    <div id="anagraficaHeader" class="accordion-pane-header" style="width: 98%;">Referente Tecnico</div>
    ............................................................
    ............................................................
    ............................................................
```

The problem is related to the last div having **id="anagraficaHeader** and **class="accordion-pane-header"** that have the following CSS settings:

```
.accordion-pane-header {
    font: 11px Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #99B1DF;
}
```

As you can see it is setted the backeground color **#99B1DF**, the problem is that doing in this way I obtain that this div (the one having **id="anagraficaHeader**) expands upwards and it falls below of the previous table (the one that have **class="standard-table-cls"** shown in the code snippet). This is the result of what I see:

[image]

Why happens this behavior? what is it the cause?

So, doing some tests I try to explicitly set an **height** to the div having class **.accordion-pane-header**, doing:

```
.accordion-pane-header {
    font: 11px Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #99B1DF;

    height: 20px
}
```

Doing so I obtain that the div have a fixed height and don't expands upwards folling below the table previously defined into the code (there are still some graphic error but these depends by other issues), as you can see in this immage:

[image]

So, I want know if specify a fixed height can be a good solution or if I do it in some smarter way.

Tnx

Comment: Nice Explanations. If you add a demo, it would be more useful

Comment: Could we have full CSS please ? That also could be because of a `.panel-wrapper` css rule (or even its children rules).

Answer (score 0):

Answer:


Sometimes the problems that you're facing lies in the upper div instead of the div in which you have encountered.

I can't clearly say why this is happening until I see complete Stylesheet. But I think this will help:

```
 .accordion-pane-header {
        display:block;
        position:relative;
        margin-top: 10px;  // margin does not allow overlapping of data
        height: 20px;  // it's good if you define particular height
        font: 11px Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px !important;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #99B1DF;
    }
```

Also, Make sure your other divs also have (as far possible)

```
display: block;
position:relative;
margin-top: //some value;
margin-bottom: //some value;
overflow: hidden;
```